# shell - Weird syntax problems (getting unexpected word exceptions where syntax is ok)

Tags: shell, unix

I'm currently working on a server start script. Everything looks perfectly ok but it won't execute so I checked the syntax using the -n flag. I gave me an error:

```
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
```

This is really weird because in is in the right place!

This is the line:

```
            case $vtyp in
```

And this is the entire code:

```
#!/bin/bash
BACKUP_PATH="$HOME/backups"
MINECRAFT_PATH="$HOME/server"
SCREEN_NAME="brain"
SERVER_JAR="minecraft.jar"
SERVER_JAR_PATH="$MINECRAFT_PATH/$SERVER_JAR"
RAM="Xmx1G";
MESSAGE_BACKUP="Backup wird erstellt..."
MESSAGE_STARTING="Server wird gestartet..."
MESSAGE_ALREADY_STARTED="Server bereits gestartet, wechsle zur Konsole..."
MESSAGE_NOT_STARTED="Fehler, nicht gestartet..."
MESSAGE_UNKNOWN="Unbekanntes Argument $1"
MESSAGE_INVALID_VERSION="Unbekannter Versionstyp."
MESSAGE_VERSIONS="Bitte Version auswählen:
1 = Stable - Stabile Version
2 = Beta - Betaversion
3 = Dev - Entwicklungsversion
"
MESSAGE_VERSION_TYPES="Versionstypen: >>stable<< - Stabile Version >>beta<< - Betaversion >>dev<< - Entwicklungsversion"

URL_JAR_STABLE=""
URL_JAR_BETA=""
URL_JAR_DEV=""

DO_BACKUP()
{
    cd $HOME
    echo $MESSAGE_BACKUP
    mkdir $BACKUP_PATH
    date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')

    tar -cjvf "$BACKUP_PATH/Complete Backup $date.tar.bz2" $MINECRAFT_PATH

    rm -rf "$MINECRAFT_PATH/server.log backups/*"
}

DO_START()
{
    cd $MINECRAFT_PATH
    echo $MESSAGE_STARTING
    screen  -A -m -d -S $SCREEN_NAME java -$RAM -jar $SERVER_JAR_PATH -o true
}

DO_REATTACH()
{
    echo $MESSAGE_ALREADY_STARTED
    screen -d -r $SCREEN_NAME
}

DO_KILL()
{
    if [ screen -list | grep -q $SCREEN_NAME ]
    then
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say Server wird gestoppt.\r"`"
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 30\r"`"
        sleep 10
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 20\r"`"
        sleep 5
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 15\r"`"
        sleep 5
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 10\r"`"
        sleep 1
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 9\r"`"
        sleep 1
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 8\r"`"
        sleep 1
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 7\r"`"
        sleep 1
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 6\r"`"
        sleep 1
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 5\r"`"
        sleep 1
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 4\r"`"
        sleep 1
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 3\r"`"
        sleep 1
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 2\r"`"
        sleep 1
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "say 1\r"`"
        sleep 1
        screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "stop\r"`"

        screen -d -r $SCREEN_NAME
    else
        echo $MESSAGE_NOT_STARTED
    fi
}

DO_NORMAL()
{
    if [ ! screen -list | grep -q $SCREEN_NAME ]
    then
        if [ ! -f $SERVER_JAR_PATH ]
        then
            DO_UPDATE
            DO_NORMAL
        else
            DO_BACKUP
            DO_START
        fi
    else
        DO_REATTACH
    fi
}

DO_UPDATE()
{
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]
    then
        while [ true ]
        do
            read -p "$MESSAGE_VERSIONS" vtyp

            case $vtyp in
                [1]*) DO_UPDATE "stable"; break;;
                [2]*) DO_UPDATE "beta"; break;;
                [3]*) DO_UPDATE "dev"; break;;
                * ) echo $MESSAGE_INVALID_VERSION;;
            esac
        done
    else
        if [ $1 = "stable" ]
        then
            mkdir $MINECRAFT_PATH
            wget $URL_JAR_STABLE -O "$SERVER_JAR_PATH"
        elif [ $1 = "beta" ]
        then
            mkdir $MINECRAFT_PATH
            wget $URL_JAR_BETA -O "$SERVER_JAR_PATH"
        elif [ $1 = "dev" ]
        then
            mkdir $MINECRAFT_PATH
            wget $URL_JAR_DEV -O "$SERVER_JAR_PATH"
        else

        echo $MESSAGE_INVALID_VERSION
        echo $MESSAGE_VERSION_TYPES
        fi
    fi
}

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    DO_NORMAL
else
    if [ $1 = "backup" ]
    then
        if screen -list | grep -q $SCREEN_NAME;
        then
            DO_KILL
            DO_BACKUP
            DO_START
        else
            DO_BACKUP
        fi
    elif [ $1 = "kill" ]
    then
        DO_KILL
    elif [ $1 = "update" ]
    then
        DO_KILL
        DO_UPDATE $2
    else
        echo $MESSAGE_UNKNOWN
    fi
fi
```

Does someone has an idea why this is happening? I'm pretty new to shell and copy pasted most of the code but as far as this goes I do understand it! And this really crushes my mind. I have no idea why this is happening.

P.S.: The same type of error occures for `elif`. Whatever comes first!

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: @devnull No difference!

Comment: Your ` if [ ! screen -list | grep -q $SCREEN_NAME ]` doesn't need the sequare brackets.  What is `[ $ \< 1 ]` supposed to be? Your `elif`s seem like a really good place for a case-statement.

Comment: `[ $ \< 1 ]` should be `[ $# \< 1 ]`. But even if I used a case statement for my elifs the case statement wouldn't work! And that's the problem!

Comment: if `[ $ \< 1 ]` should be `[ $# \< 1 ]` then use `[ $# -lt 1 ]` instead.

Comment: In `case $vtyp in`, what is the value of `$vtyp`? Does quoting it help? `case "$vtyp" in`

Comment: No it does not help. The value is determined by a read command. Just look in the entire code!

Comment: @glennjackman This does not even relate to the problem!

Comment: Not *this* problem, but the next one: `foo() { if [ $ \< 1 ]; then echo OK; else echo bad; fi; }` then call it with no args and then call it with 1 arg and let me know if you think it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps doing this would help: In PSPad -- Format --> Unix
http://forum.pspad.com/read.php?2,52821,52831

Comment: Ok. This seems to work. I have another problem now which I will explain in the start post!

Comment: I guess `screen -list | grep -q $SCREEN_NAME` needs to be enclosed between square brackets

Comment: still the same problem :(

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but a code review: I would rewrite the DO_UPDATE function:

First

```
MESSAGE_VERSION_PROMPT="Bitte Version auswählen: "
MESSAGE_VERSIONS=(
    "Stable - Stabile Version"
    "Beta - Betaversion"
    "Dev - Entwicklungsversion"
)
```

Then

```
DO_UPDATE()
{
    if (( $# == 0 )); then
        local PS3="$MESSAGE_VERSION_PROMPT"
        select choice in "${MESSAGE_VERSIONS[@]}"; do
            case $REPLY in
                1) set -- stable; break ;;
                2) set -- beta  ; break ;;
                3) set -- dev   ; break ;;
            esac
        done
    fi
    case $1 in
        stable)
            mkdir $MINECRAFT_PATH
            wget $URL_JAR_STABLE -O "$SERVER_JAR_PATH"
            ;;
        beta)
            mkdir $MINECRAFT_PATH
            wget $URL_JAR_BETA -O "$SERVER_JAR_PATH"
            ;;
        dev)
            mkdir $MINECRAFT_PATH
            wget $URL_JAR_DEV -O "$SERVER_JAR_PATH"
            ;;
        *) 
            echo $MESSAGE_INVALID_VERSION
            echo $MESSAGE_VERSION_TYPES
            return 1
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: Thanks ;) This is by far better! But there seem to be issues with the array. I get a sytax error! `15: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` line 15 is the first line of the array (`MESSAGE_VERSIONS=(`)

Comment: What version of bash do you have?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy-paste from a word or notepad file? Try using `dos2unix`

Comment: I copied it from pastebin. And I don't have the dos2unix command. Could I fix this with my texteditor? (I'm using PSPad)

Comment: @BrainStone if you use `vim`, you can fix this by running `:set fileformat=unix`. No idea about PSPad.

Comment: I'm not using vim and working on my script on a windows machine and uploading it with a ftp client.